# Востановление пароля

Tags: php

Написал скрипт востановления пароля, все работает, но когда прходит на почту, то он шифруется, в базу пароль добавляется, но мне надо без шифровки.

```
    <?php
include ('bd.php');

if ($email = $_POST['email'] )
    {
// проверяем, если юзер в таблице с таким же мылом
$query = "SELECT login, email, pass FROM `users` WHERE email ='{$email}' LIMIT 1 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT login, email, pass FROM `users` WHERE email ='{$email}' LIMIT 1";
        $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($res)==1)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

//если есть
 $login = $row['login']; 
 $email = $row['email']; 
 $pass = $row['pass']; 
  }
# 
# 
# /* тема/subject */

# 
# /* сообщение */ 
 $message = 'У вас новое сообщение, напоминаем ваш пароль: '.$pass.'
 '; 
# 
# /* Для отправки HTML-почты вы можете установить шапку Content-type. */ 
 $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
# 
# /* дополнительные шапки */

$headers .= "From:domain.com <info@domain.com>\r\n"; 
$subject = "Здравствуйте, $login! Напоминание пароля.";

#
# /* и теперь отправим из */ 
 mail($email, "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=", $message, $headers);

        echo '

<center><h2>Пароль отправлен на Ваш Email!</h2></center>

 ';
}else{

    echo'<center><h2>Не зарегистрированый или не правельный Email!</h2></center>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас пароль хранится в виде хэша (что правильно), то никакими средствами вы его оттуда не вытащите (пока у вас в сервере не стоит восемь GPU).

И это правильно. Только создание пароля заново, никаких напоминаний. В этом случае в интернете никто, никто не узнает настоящий пароль, чего вы и должны добиваться.

> Не зарегистрированый или не правельный

:facepalm:

Comment: судя по 

    SELECT login, email, pass FROM `users` WHERE email ='{$email}' LIMIT 1

в базе у вас все-таки хэш. Можете сами проверить (не через pma, а через какой-нибудь xdebug или var_dump)  
и да, UNION-то там зачем?

Comment: Спасибо, я уже исправил.